# How to show/hide specific objects based on variables in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, indesign-scripting

I'm creating a 80-page product catalog for a clothing company. Each page contains one clothing item. 
On each page, there is a table that contains four pieces of information about that clothing item:

1. Washing recommendations (Indicated by placed .ai files for handwash, No tumble dry etc)
2. Available sizes, 3 scenarios: Onesize, S M L, or S/M and M/L (.psd files)
3. Material: Cotton, wool or bamboo. (.ai files)
4. Available colors (indicated by colored rectangles)

Of course, it's a lot of work and there are huge risks for inconsistencies etc to do all this manually for 80 pages.

Can we use InDesign like a webshop where you'd tick boxes for each of these properties for a product/page, and InDesign would show or hide the relevant graphics in their right places based on that info, with the correct dimensions, placing, etc?

Or, are there any other ways to do this in a smart, consistent way?

Comment: Its possible to make tickboxes but like in a webshop, talk to your onsite programmer about this. Personally i would just use xml ...

Comment: That sounds like halfway to an answer, how would you use XML to solve this?